# How to add success notification after form submit

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf, pnotify

I would like to add success notification after user submitted the form.

I've already checked out the Pnotify js library -https://sciactive.com/pnotify/, which looks nice. But no idea how I can use in my CRUD project. I'm using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf for a frontend.

I checked docs:

```
<button class="btn btn-default source" onclick="new PNotify({
                              title: 'Regular Success',
                              text: 'That thing that you were trying to do worked!',
                              type: 'success',
                              styling: 'bootstrap3'
                          });">Success</button>
```

This is my form:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/contractors-save}"
    th:object="${contractor}"
    method="post" class="form-horizontal form-label-left">

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
        <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" class="form-control"
                placeholder="name"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Description</label>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
        <input type="text" th:field="*{description}"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="description"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
            data-dismiss="modal">
        Close
    </button>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success">
</div>
```

The notification is showing on click action, in my case I need to show after form submission. 
Could you advise and share with your expertise? Maybe other alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative.

You can follow [`PRG`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern and use [`RedirectAttributes`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html) to add flash attributes.

For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/contractor", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handle(@Valid @ModelAttribute Contractor contractor,
                     BindingResult result,
                     RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    // Save contactor ...

    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Successful!");

    return "redirect:/someGetUrl";
}
```

And just show this `message` in the view rendered by `/someGetUrl` handler.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, also got this idea! Later on, will post my implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I followed PRG pattern, as @Minar Mahmud suggested, will share with my implementation:

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/contractor-save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveContractor(@ModelAttribute(value = "contractor") Contractor contractor,
                         RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    Contractor savedContractor = contractorService.save(contractor);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("notification",
        String.format("Contractor \"%s\" successfully saved", savedContractor.getName()));
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("action", "save");

return "redirect:/contractors";
```

}

And in HTML file, showing notification on page load with javascript:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var notification = /*[[${notification}]]*/ "";
    var action = /*[[${action}]]*/ "";
    if (action === 'save') {
        new PNotify({
            title: 'Save contractor',
            text: notification,
            type: 'success',
            styling: 'bootstrap3',
            delay: 3000
        });
    } else if (action === 'remove') {
        new PNotify({
            title: 'Remove contractor',
            text: notification,
            type: 'success',
            styling: 'bootstrap3',
            delay: 3000
        });
    } else if (action === 'update') {
        new PNotify({
            title: 'Edit contractor',
            text: notification,
            type: 'success',
            styling: 'bootstrap3',
            delay: 3000
        });
    }
});
```

Please fill free to comment. I would like to know is it ok for production? Just to be sure that I'm not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @eabushev. I am not familiar with Pnotify library. But the approach seems ok to me. +1